# Problems using stat_countour() in a map (ggplot2. R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have a data frame with locations (latitude + longitude) in Eurasia and I would like to use a third variable to create a contour map. The data frame (datgeo) looks like this:

```
lat       long      date_BP
56.28000  25.13000  7429.833
40.31992  29.45311  8048.077
50.41027  14.07460  4200.000
50.12175  14.45695  4484.600
58.74000  -2.91600  4913.444
44.53000  22.05000  8200.333
50.09000  74.44000  3707.125
34.75146  72.40194  2834.625
...
```

I use ggplot2 to generate a map of Eurasia. And I tried to use date_BP as the z-axis to create the contour map

```
library (ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(ggspatial)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data = datgeo, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  stat_contour(geom="polygon",data=datgeo, aes(x=long,y=lat,z=date_BP,fill=..level..)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-12.3, 110), ylim = c(70, 30), expand = FALSE)
```

However, the script didn't work at all and I could not get a contour map.
This is the map that the above script generates:
[image]

Why this script is not representing any contour lines (isobars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that `stat_contour` does not work because it needs a complete grid. I found this blog's article that explain how to deal with this issue: https://www.r-statistics.com/2016/07/using-2d-contour-plots-within-ggplot2-to-visualize-relationships-between-three-variables/

I used this blog's answer to build the following answer adapted to your question and the minimal example you provided.

First, you need to create a predicted model based on your restricted dataset "datgeo".

```r
data_geo_loess <- loess(date_BP ~lat+long, data = datgeo)
```

Then, you can create a grid of values with lat, long values:

```r
lat_grid <- seq(min(datgeo$lat),max(datgeo$lat),0.1)
long_grid <- seq(min(datgeo$long), max(datgeo$long),0.1)
data_grid <- expand.grid(lat = lat_grid, long = long_grid)
```

Now, you can use the `loess` model to calculate theorical values of date_BP based on all values of lat and long you have generated and we will reshape on order to get a suitable dataframe for `ggplot2`:

```r
geo_fit <- predict(data_geo_loess, newdata = data_grid)

library(reshape2)
geo_fit <- melt(geo_fit, id.vars = c("lat","long"), measure.vars = "date_BP")

library(stringr)
geo_fit$lat <- as.numeric(str_sub(geo_fit$lat, str_locate(geo_fit$lat, "=")[1,1] + 1))
geo_fit$long <- as.numeric(str_sub(geo_fit$long, str_locate(geo_fit$long, "=")[1,1] + 1))

> head(geo_fit)
       lat   long    value
1 34.75146 -2.916 24170.02
2 34.85146 -2.916 24290.79
3 34.95146 -2.916 24381.19
4 35.05146 -2.916 24442.12
5 35.15146 -2.916 24474.53
6 35.25146 -2.916 24479.34
```

Finally, you can get your plot by doing:

```r
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(rnaturalearth)

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-12.3, 110), ylim = c(70, 30), expand = FALSE) +
  stat_contour(geom="polygon",
               inherit.aes = FALSE, 
               data=geo_fit, alpha = 0.5, fill = NA,
               aes(x=long,y=lat,z=value, color=..level..)) +
  geom_point(data = datgeo, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

[image]

Does it look what you are expecting ?

---

NB: `loess` model will return some warnings (at least in my case) because there is too few observations to build a reliable model. So, you will have to see with your real and more complete data if it is working.

NB: An alternative solution will be to use `stat_density_2d` but you can't use a third dimensional value.

---

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(lat = c(56.28, 40.31992, 50.41027, 50.12175, 58.74, 
44.53, 50.09, 34.75146), long = c(25.13, 29.45311, 14.0746, 14.45695, 
-2.916, 22.05, 74.44, 72.40194), date_BP = c(7429.833, 8048.077, 
4200, 4484.6, 4913.444, 8200.333, 3707.125, 2834.625)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The data I share it was just the first 6 rows of a total of 250. However, the results are not as I expected. I used also stat_density2d. And have better results. However I had a problem including geom_point:

Comment: You should edit your question to describe this problem and the code you are using in order we can propose you some solutions

Comment: Ok, it is done! Its weird how the plot changes just for adding geom_point(). If you need the dataset I can also share it.

Comment: I have another question. I'm trying to obtain, instead of lines, areas with colors, like the maps I shared below. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I want to thanks dc37 for the help!

I used `stat_density2d` but I'm getting some weird results.

This is the first approach:

```
world <- map_data("world")
plot <- ggplot()
plot <- ggplot(data=datgeo, aes(long,lat,fill=date_BP)) + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon',
                 colour='black') + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") + guides(alpha="none")
plot <- plot + geom_map(dat=world, map = world, aes(map_id=region), 
                        fill="NA", color="black", inherit.aes = F)
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), 
                     panel.border=element_blank())
plot <- plot + coord_sf(xlim = c(-12.3, 110), ylim = c(70, 30), expand = FALSE)
windows()
plot
```

The plot I obtained is this one:
[image]

I don't understand the scale of the legend since my data the max value is 45020 and the min is 736. I don´t know how to change this.

Now, If I want to add geom_point() Things get weird:

```
world <- map_data("world")
plot <- ggplot()
plot <- ggplot(data=datgeo, aes(long,lat,fill=date_BP)) + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon',
                 colour='black') + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") + guides(alpha="none")
plot <- plot + geom_map(dat=world, map = world, aes(map_id=region), 
                        fill="NA", color="black", inherit.aes = F)
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), 
                     panel.border=element_blank())
plot <- plot + coord_sf(xlim = c(-12.3, 110), ylim = c(70, 30), expand = FALSE)
plot <- plot + geom_point(data = datgeo, aes(x = long, y = lat))
windows()
plot
```

And I get this map:
[image]

You can see that now I have the points, the colors of the isobars changed and the scale of the legend is in the correct format. I don't understand why the map changes like this just for adding points.

Do you know what is happening and which one is the correct map?

Comment: First, `stat_density_2d` does not take a third value as input for the filling. The filling is based on the density of points. So, the value in legend on the first graph are density values. Second, you call this legend "Date_BP", so when you add `geom_point`, the legend were added to legend of `stat_density_2d` make you fill that the are in right scale. So far, I don't know which function will make the graph you are looking for.

Comment: Ok. I see. I have a question. The first one, it is based on the density of date_BP? As I defined  ```ggplot(data=datgeo, aes(long,lat,fill=date_BP))``` Or is the density of the number of points in that lat and long? And why the colours of the first and second figure change that much? Sorry, I'm still a little bit lost!
What I'm trying to represent is the the isobar of the dates of different sites in Euorope. so the colours must gather lat and long with the same date. I believe that in my case what I need is ```stat_density2d```
Thank you very much for your help